# How to deserialize an object type back to it's original type?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a class like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public string UnderlyingItemString { get; set; }
    public object UnderlyingItem { get; set; }
}
```

Property `UnderlyingItem` can be different types.

How to I deserialize it back to whatever it's original type is? I do store the `UnderlyingItem`'s object name in `UnderlyingItemString`

I do this code below to deserialize it which puts `UnderlyingItem` as a `JObject` but I need it to be one of the custom classes I have created.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(myJSON);
```

Comment: Are you able to change `MyClass` to be generic?

Comment: Reflection will give you that information in your class. No need to store it.

Comment: @GHDevOps yes, but once you searilize the class, how is the deserializer going to tell the difference between a `string[]` and a `List<string>`, or a `double` and `decimal`?

Comment: @gunr2171 I can't make `MyClass` generic

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible scheme that, when [tested](https://github.com/IVSoftware/type-from-string.git) with the four types mentioned by gunr2171, seems to work. It adds an `UnderlyingTypeName` property to serialize the full type name and meets the requirement that the `MyClass` cannot be generic.

The `UnderlyingItem` property itself is ignored by the json serializer. The getter for this property queries the loaded assemblies to find one containing the target type. If found, the json deserializer uses the specific type. Otherwise the default Json.Net deserializer is invoked.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public string UnderlyingItemString { get; set; }
    public string UnderlyingTypeName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public object UnderlyingItem
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UnderlyingItemString))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                Type type = typeof(object);
                Assembly assy = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UnderlyingTypeName))
                    assy =
                        AppDomain
                        .CurrentDomain
                        .GetAssemblies()
                        .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.GetType(UnderlyingTypeName) != null);
                if (assy == null)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(UnderlyingItemString);
                }
                else
                {
                    type = assy.GetType(UnderlyingTypeName);
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(UnderlyingItemString, type);
                }
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_UnderlyingItem, value))
            {
                _UnderlyingItem = value;
                UnderlyingItemString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
                UnderlyingTypeName = _UnderlyingItem.GetType().FullName;
            }
        }
    }
    private object _UnderlyingItem = new object();
}
```

---

**Testbench**

[image: test output showing four types]

`string[]`

```
MyClass testRoundTripIn, testRoundTripOut;
string json;
Type returnedType;

testRoundTripIn = new MyClass
{
    UnderlyingItem = new string[] { "A", "B", "C"},
};
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testRoundTripIn, Formatting.Indented);

testRoundTripOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

returnedType = testRoundTripOut.UnderlyingItem.GetType();
if (typeof(string[]).Equals(returnedType))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MyClass.UnderlyingItem deserialized as {returnedType.FullName}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error string[] Deserialized as {returnedType.Name}");
}
```

`List<string>`

```
testRoundTripIn = new MyClass
{
    UnderlyingItem = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C"},
};
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testRoundTripIn, Formatting.Indented);

testRoundTripOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

returnedType = testRoundTripOut.UnderlyingItem.GetType();
if (typeof(List<string>).Equals(returnedType))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MyClass.UnderlyingItem deserialized as {returnedType.Name}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error List<string> deserialized as {returnedType.FullName}");
}
```

`double`

```
testRoundTripIn = new MyClass
{
    UnderlyingItem = Math.PI,
};
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testRoundTripIn, Formatting.Indented);

testRoundTripOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

returnedType = testRoundTripOut.UnderlyingItem.GetType();
if (typeof(double).Equals(returnedType))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MyClass.UnderlyingItem deserialized as {returnedType.Name}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error double deserialized as {returnedType.FullName}");
}
```

`decimal`

```
testRoundTripIn = new MyClass
{
    UnderlyingItem = 1.23m,
};
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testRoundTripIn, Formatting.Indented);

testRoundTripOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

returnedType = testRoundTripOut.UnderlyingItem.GetType();
if (typeof(decimal).Equals(returnedType))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"MyClass.UnderlyingItem deserialized as {returnedType.Name}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error decimal deserialized as {returnedType.FullName}");
}
```